# MVC4 CSHTML load TEXT fields from database

Tags: c#, razor

I have one system on WebForms and I did a load text fields from database and choice the correct place for each one easy by ID, but in cshtml I thinking on the best way for this, I check for [DisplayName("foo bar")] on models, but I need to complete the others common buttons of Web, so I am embarrassing about the a lot of code I need to see that working well, maybe I am wrong about my concept. Any idea or best way? thanks.
*Each user need to have a choice to change the name of buttos,labels,.... any time. Database is ready to use*.

web fields

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataInicioAcesso)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInicioAcesso)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataInicioAcesso)
    </div>
```

And

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Acesso_Usuario                                ",   "Index",  "Acesso_Usuario")</li>
```

And

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
```

And others... I have a SessionPermissionLogin all configured. So I want each one read a diferent text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way and cleaner way would be to create a custom [DisplayName] metadata to display labels dynamically. Something like [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Customizing-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Metadata-and-Validation.aspx) and [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/06/14/asp.net-mvc-localization-displaynameattribute-alternatives-a-good-way.aspx)

```
public class DynamicDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute 
    {
        public DynamicDisplayNameAttribute(string key)
        {
            _key = key;
         }

        public override string DisplayName
        {
            get
    {
         //
         //repo database logic to get display name
         //
          string displayName = repo.GetDisplayName(key);

          return string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName)
             ?"" 
             : displayName;
      }
  }

  private string _key { get; set; }
```

}

Add attribute to a property like

```
      [DynamicDisplayNameAttribute("Key")]
      public string DataInicioAcesso { get; set; }
```

Comment: Works so great! beautiful. But I working to others best ways to find the same atributes for simple buttons. And now I want get other values ` >>>>>>[MaxLength(128)]<<<<<< [AtributosInModels("Senha")]` So I am implementing a clonnable pattern to avoid other database access. soon post the result code if is interesting. thanks @EmmanualN